# Passing variable precision to TIMEFROMPARTS function

Tags: sql, function, time, sql-server-2014, data-conversion

I'm trying to build a function that takes a string as input representing a time variable with no separators. The fraction part could have variable precision.

This is the code I came up with :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Convert_FullStringToTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @inputString VARCHAR(17),
    @fractionsPrecision INT = 0
)
RETURNS TIME(7)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result TIME(7)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Result = 
        TIMEFROMPARTS(
            LEFT(@inputString, 2),                      --hh
            SUBSTRING(@inputString, 3, 2),              --mm
            SUBSTRING(@inputString, 5, 2),              --ss
            RIGHT(@inputString, @fractionsPrecision),   --ff
            @fractionsPrecision
        )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Scale argument is not valid. Valid expressions for data type time scale argument are integer constants and integer constant expressions.

Do I have to understand I really have to write a constant for the precision parameter ???
Why on earth has this been done that way ?

Is there a better solution than using a case statement to overcome this ridiculous problem ?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Also, considering that your function will always return a `time(7)`, why do you want a variable precision within the function? This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Indeed the return value should become `Time(7)` as you mentionned, I was expecting the return value to right pad  the time with 0. I'll just change the approach by padding the fraction input with 0, should do the trick I guess...

Comment: *"Why on earth has this been done that way ?"* Because a value must be well defined; T-SQL is a declarative and compiled language. If you had the query `SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(0,0,0,0,V.I) AS T FROM (VALUES(5),(6),(7))V(I)` it would be impossible for SQL Server to determine the data type for the column aliased as `T`; should it be a `time(5)`, `time(6)`, or `time(7)`?

Comment: Indeed, you two pointed out the precision was inherent to the data type. You can write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it ! Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm only one person, @Axel, not two. ;) (An account being used by two or more people is actually against the ToS here.)

Comment: Haha, mb, thought the last answer came from someone else x) (Sorry, i'm a bit in a rush right now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually telling you that what you want to do is explicitly not allowed. The precision parameter for `TIMEFORPARTS` *must* be a literal; it cannot be an expression, a column value or a variable. For your `FUNCTION` there is, in truth, little/no point in having a "variable" precision value either; a `FUNCTION` *must* also have an explicit data type defined and that include the length/scale/precision. You initially had your `FUNCTION` defined as a `time`, which is a synonym for `time(7)`, and you have now change the `FUNCTION` to demonstrate that. As such it wouldn't matter what value the precision was passed, your `FUNCTION` would *always* return a `time(7)`.

To address your latter comments:

> Why on earth has this been done that way ?
>
> Is there a better solution than using a case statement to overcome this ridiculous problem ?

I'm going to address your second comment first; it isn't a "ridiculous problem", the real problem is you want a value that doesn't have a strict definition. T-SQL is a declarative and compiled langauge; you need to explicity define what data types a value is. The fact you want a variable precision value is a strong indication of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info), however, what that problem is I don't know. There likely is a "better solution" to what you *actually* want to do, but without knowing what that is, we can't access that question here.

As for *why* it's done that way, I come back to the point of that the language  is declarative and compiled; as such if you *could* pass a variable/expression then SQL Sevrer would know what data type to compile a column as. Take the following very simple statement:

```sql
SELECT TIMEFROMPARTS(0,0,0,0,V.I) AS T
FROM (VALUES(5),(6),(7))V(I)
```

Here the column `V.I` being (trying to be) used to define the precision for `TIMEFROMPARTS`. The problem though is that `V.I` has 3 different values, `5`, `6`, and `7`, so what is the data type for the column defined as `T`? Should it be `7`? `5`? SQL Server doesn't know, because at the time it compiles the statement it cannot make an informed decision; for a table (rather than a `VALUES` table construct) the compiler wouldn't read the table first to then make a decision, that would be *awful* for performance.

As such you *must* use a literal to tell SQL Server what precision you need. Just like when you define a variable, you can't use the syntax `varchar(@Len)` or when you `CONVERT` a column you can't use the syntax `CONVERT(decimal(T.P,T.S),MyColumn)`.

Answer (score 0):

This the combination of function I came up with, taking into account the precision inherent to the `TIME` datatype. (Thanks to [@Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu))

First, the padding function (which SQL SERVER also lacks...)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Rpad] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @inputString VARCHAR(MAX),
    @paddingCharacter VARCHAR(1),
    @paddingLength INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Result = 
        LEFT(@inputString + REPLICATE(@paddingCharacter, @paddingLength), @paddingLength)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Then the Time conversion function, which will always return a 7 precision TIME data type.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Convert_FullStringToTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @inputString VARCHAR(13)
)
RETURNS TIME(7)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @Result TIME(7)

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @Result = 
        TIMEFROMPARTS(
                LEFT(@inputString, 2),                        --hh
                SUBSTRING(@inputString, 3, 2),                --mm
                SUBSTRING(@inputString, 5, 2),                --ss
                RIGHT([dbo].RPAD(@inputString, '0', 7), 7),   --ff
                7
            )


    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: `VARCHAR(MAX)` for a *time* value? A time will never be over 8,000 characters so why use a data type that explicitly states it's likely to be? Why are you not using a `time` for a *time* value? This isn't a good answer.

Comment: The RPAD function is not intended to be exclusively used with the TimeFromPart. The input string for the time function is VARCHAR(17) (and should actually be 13 !)

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything on what this is actually trying to achieve, or why you need 8,000+ characters for value that will never over 8,000 characters. This answer doesn't answer the question you asked; you've answers the X from the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) but as you asked about Y, we don't know what that X is. If you wanted to post this as an answer, you should be posting a *new* question asking about X.

Comment: Why would you want to restrict the rpad function input/output length (whose use feels kinda intuitive) ? I agree that, in this case, it's not gonna use more than 13 chars, but I might use RPAD to right pad a string with a length of 1000 or more (altought I doubt I'll ever have to). What I'm trying to acheive is simply converting a string to a TIME(7) data type. LEt's says that's the X problem, and since you told me how Time precision worked,  there's no Y problem anymore, right ?

Comment: But your question is still about *Y* so this answer doesn't make sense for the question. What does padding a string have to do with the function you had, that wanted a variable precision on a `time`..? A `time` is a binary value, so you *can't* "pad" it; the way the value is formatted is a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: Question was indeed about y, but y was clearly there to answer x. As i mentioned, you removed y from the equation, and you even described why in your answer... do we really have to go on with this discussion ? x) I just added my answer to point how I solved x, cause i expected you to answer y, which you did ! Note that, I did not yet mentionned that you were also right for the parameter fractionPrecision, which can now be removed ;)